# Bot don’t respond using rasa

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Need help please.

My bot respond with correct answer during the online training, and when I confirm the answer he want to give, it works (use a custom action to asnwer). How ever when I try my bot with actual dialogue It don’t work.

the sénarion will be like:

User: Bonjour

Bot: Bonjour écrivez votre problème

User: mon probleme est: bla bla

Nothing from bot

This sénario is when trying to run the bot.
But before that when using online training the bot respond correctly with the custom action.

In my stories file I have something like:

```
## Generated Story -960033508281559891
bonjour
    - utter_bonjour
confirmer
    - utter_etape1
problème_site
    - SendIntent_probleme_site
    - utter_problème_site
```

So according to my story file the bot should do the action SendIntent_probleme_site. The class for this action is:

```
class SendIntent_probleme_site(Action): 
    def name(self): 
        return ‘SendIntent_probleme_site’ 
    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain): 
        message = tracker.latest_message.text  
        return [SlotSet(‘intent_probleme_site’, message)]
```

I do this to store the intent_probleme as a slot to use it later

Any help please? I also don’t know how to do something that tell me were is the problem like a log or exception, etc.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Rasa Core are you using?

Comment: rasa_core version: 0.9.6

Comment: When loging my bot here is what I get when the bot do not respond:

    [11/26/2018 10:21:36] DEBUG:There is no memorised next action
    [11/26/2018 10:21:36] DEBUG:Predicted next action using 
    policy_0_KerasPolicy
    [11/26/2018 10:21:36] DEBUG:Predicted next action 'action_listen' with 
    prob 0.55.
    [11/26/2018 10:21:36] DEBUG:Action 'action_listen' ended with events '[]'
    [11/26/2018 10:21:36] DEBUG:Current topic: None

Comment: What message are you sending to the bot?
Please consider upgrading Rasa Core. Rasa Core is a young framework and iterating quickly. Hence, version 0.9.6 is way behind

Comment: My bot is in french. In my stories I have something like:

    '* bonjour
    - utter_bonjour
* confirmer
    - utter_etape1
* problème_site
    - SendIntent_probleme_site
    - utter_problème_site'

the bot block in the final one in the log it recognize the phrase "plusieurs personnes ne participent pas" as probleme_site intent. but instead of doing the costum action and then utter_probleme_site, it do nothing. the costum action store the last message as slot

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do a code like in the message here in comments

Comment: Did upgrade for rasa_core and now I'am getting the UnicodeDecoderError: 'utf8'.. issue. I'am trying to solve this, didn't have this before

Comment: So you are now on `0.12.2`? Try replacing your `è`. Also create an issue including your error message if you are on `0.12.2`  on https://github.com/rasahq/rasa_core/issues , please :-)

Comment: Ok sir, will try replacing é and create an issue if it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: no, please start an issue for the unicode thing. We can continue the rest here :-)

Comment: now I'am getting the issue to do the online training; the first code don't work. Because I used ConsoleInputChannel. And I found that this one has been removed, Iam trying to found how to do it

Comment: Just train your core model, and start core with `python -m rasa_core.run -d models`. No need for any custom code there. For interactive learning do something like `python -m rasa_core.train interactive -s stories.md -d domain.yml -u default/<your model name>`

Comment: Yes I've done this, the bot seem to be more true when responding, now with the custom actions I've done the new methode "endpoints, etc." but when the bot should execute the first custom action it tell me: the bot want to run 'action_default_fallback' I guess I'am not writing actions as it should be for the new version. I Have custom action for example action_sendintentprobleme and in my stories I call it with the same name, and in the domain file in actions: - action_sendintentprobleme. I'am realy sorry Iam new to this and Have a project to finish. This is why Asking a lot

Comment: Have you already connected NLU? Which NLU pipeline are you using? I can recommend https://forum.rasa.com since there is larger community for Rasa than here.

Comment: Yes already connected. I'am posting my questions now in forum.rasa, I'am trying to solve this not working for now. Will create an issue